# Select funciona perfeitamente, mas quando a mesma é passada como função retorna erro

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-select

Estou enfrentando um dilema que parece ser simples de resolver, mas não consigo enxergar onde está o erro.

Tenho um SELECT COUNT(*) que funciona corretamente, mas quando o mesmo é passado como função ocorre o erro **Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in "blah blah blah on line 35**.

```
$conn =  mysqli_connect($hostName, $userName, $keyWord);
if (!$conn) {die('Falha ao estabelecer conexão com o banco de dados: '. mysqli_connect_error());};

if (!mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbName)) {
    $create_DB = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " .$dbName;
    mysqli_query($conn, $create_DB);
    mysqli_select_db($conn, $DB);
}

echo $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_rows FROM tabelaDeTeste WHERE sexo = "masculino"';
echo "</br>";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($conn));
$count = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
//$count = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

if ($count["count_rows"] > 0) {
    echo $count["count_rows"];
} 

echo "</br>..........................................</br>";

function count_rows($table_name, $condition) {
    echo $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_rows FROM '.$table_name.' '.$condition; 
    echo "</br>";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($conn));
    $count = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    //$count = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if ($count["count_rows"] > 0) {
        echo $count["count_rows"];
    }
}

count_rows('tabelaDeTeste', 'WHERE sexo = "masculino"');
```

Retorno:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já agradeço a atenção e aguardo retorno.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Dentro de `count_rows()`, no início da função, coloque:

```
global $conn;
```

Comment: Marcelo, resolveu sim o meu problema. Mas vejo tantos rumores de que usar variáveis globais não é uma boa pratica que acabei nem me lembrando dessa alternativa. Há outra forma de está resolvendo isso sem o uso de variáveis globais?

Comment: @Skyline Bastaria passar a conexão como parâmetro: `function count_rows($conn, $table_name, $condition) { etc }` e para chamar a função: `count_rows($conn, 'tabelaDeTeste', 'WHERE sexo = "masculino"')`